# Binary Bomb Phase 2 - Decoding Assembly

Tags: assembly

I'm currently trying to figure out what the six passcode integers are for this function. Every other example I've looked at, on this site and others, has used a "je" instruction for the first comparison, which allows us to deduce what the first integer input should be, however, the "bomb" that I'm working on seems to be using a "js" after the first comparison. I can't for the life of me figure out what the first input should be, let alone the other 5. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Here is assembly for the phase_2 with my annotations of what I believe is going on:

[image]

I've been able to figure out that the read_six_numbers function is expecting six integers seperated by a space as input. Though, without the first correct integer input, I can't step through the function enough to examine any register values that might hold the next correct integers that the input is compared against. I'm at a loss.

Comment: `js` check the sign bit. When a 2-complement number has the sign bit set? The other numbers are easy to find if you just annotate the code. You can test your hypothesis with a debugger.

Comment: What do you mean by check the sign bit? I'm sorry, I'm a complete beginner when it comes to assembly.

Comment: The sign bit is the Most significant bit, see the 2 complement format. Also, your annotations, while probably not wrong, just describe the semantics of an instruction (e.g. read from X into Y). It's better if you turn that instruction semantics into a meaningful operation (e.g. `y = input[i]`).

Comment: Gotcha, thank you very much Margaret. That is great advice.